# Prove that $x\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: solution-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

Not too sure how to compute this. I can prove that $\sin(x)$ is continuous for all real numbers $x$ and hence $x=0$. I also know how to prove that $x$ is continuous for all real numbers $x$ and hence $x=0$. Then I could use the algebra of continuous functions product rule to show that this must mean $x\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x$ = 0.

There must be an easier way though right. My other thought:

I can prove using the sandwich theorem that |$x$||$\sin(x)$| = $0$ (or just trivially state it actually), so |$x$||$\sin(x)$| = $0$ < $\epsilon$, since $\epsilon$ > 0 as stated.

Cheers : )

Comment: Can you prove any product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: what do you mean (2nd sentence): "and hence x=0"?

Comment: @311411 “… and hence [$x\mapsto x$ is continuous at] $x=0$”, I suspect

Comment: Your first thought is correct and imo easy, you can’t really make it simpler than that. The second thought is wrong since continuity is about checking values of $x$ *near to*, but not at, zero.

Comment: @311411 If the function is continuous for all real numbers, it must be continuous at x = 0 then. Should have made it clearer maybe.

Comment: Have you used limits(for the question in the title)? The limits tend to zero, and it's zero atx=0, thus it's continuous

Comment: @FShrike Yes I can. I can do it the long way or using the algebra of limits and theorem that if the limit as x tends to a of f(x) = f(a), then f is continuous at a. Okay good to know why my 2nd method is wrong

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever So you're saying that if I can prove the limit tends to zero as x tends to zero (using the squeeze theorem), then the function must be continuous at x = 0 using that theorem ?

Comment: If you can proove that the absolute value of $f$ is continous, you can easily proove that $f$ is continous. Try using epsilon delta for it, it is really easy

Comment: @NikitaMazepin if you prove that the left and right limits are both 0, and also note that f(0)=0, then it is continuous by the definition of continuity.

Comment: oh, nevermind, @NikitaMazepin, didn't see the epsilon-delta tag, I'm only familiar with newton's definition at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @QED "$|f(x)|$ continuous" does not imply "$f(x)$ continous". As an easy counterexample take $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x\ge 0$

Comment: @peter For the limit beeing 0 it does

Comment: @FShrike Could I also use the theorem that a function is continuous at a if and only if the limit as x tends to a of the function = f(a). So if I can prove that lim x -> 0 of xsinx = 0, that would prove it's continuous ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin It would prove it's continuous at zero, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity:

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ if 
for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that 
$0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$

Consider this function, here, $f(x)=x\sin x$, $x_0=0$, and $f(x_0)=0$

Consider a given $\epsilon$. For that $\epsilon$, consider $\delta=\epsilon$ 
$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |x| < \delta $
Thus $|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |x \sin x - 0| \leq |x||\sin x| \leq |x| < \delta  \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon  $

And we're done!